# Javascript + REGEX to get first non-zero number from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've read through all the suggested questions, but all are dealing with decimals numbers (where math functions are useful) or with single characters like a comma.

I have a string "EH00011" from which I need to extract the number portion so I can iterate and output "EH00012." I tried simply getting the last five characters and using parseInt(). This works for single-digit instances (00005) but not for 10-19 or any other number which could be interpreted as binary. In the case of 00011 it converts to 9, then iterates to 10, rather than converting to 11 and iterating to 12. The best idea I've thought of outside of Regex would be to loop through each character until I get to a non-zero and then output everything after. But I figured there must be a better way with regex.

So, I need a regex (or some other method above my thought process) that can take a string "00011" and output 11. I figured it would do the same as my loop option and look for the first non-zero value and return everything including and after that character.

**EDIT**: As suggested, I simply added the radix parameter set to 10 and it works perfectly. No REGEX or other additional code needed!

Comment: Is expected result `"EH00012."` or `"12"`?

Comment: Sound like you have not specified the radix for the parseInt() i.e. parseInt(12) will default to octal whereas parseInt(12,10) will force decimal. What browser are you using because most JS engines now have the default radix of 10 set.

Comment: For simplicity, you can also use `/[1-9][0-9]*/` with `match` and extract the first item. `.match(/[1-9][0-9]*/)[0]`

Comment: ^^ Love the solution above!

Comment: @jeff I'm on Google Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `parseInt` without a radix you'll get octal for strings beginning with 0. Rather than using `parseInt` I've used a unary `+` in my example, which doesn't suffer from that problem. The RegExp guarantees that we won't have to contend with non-integers or `0x` prefixed hex.

```js
var str = 'EH0000000';

for (var i = 0 ; i < 20 ; ++i) {
    str = str.replace(/\d+$/, function(num) {
        var out = `${+num + 1}`;
        return num.slice(0, -out.length) + out;
    });

    console.log(str);
}
```

I've anchored my RegExp to the end of the string using `$`. That isn't strictly required but without knowing exactly what the format is that seemed like a sensible precaution.

To do the 0 padding I've just sliced the original string form of the number. The key thing here is when we hit the powers of 10, we need `009` to become `010` and not `0010`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseInt()` in combination with regex:

```
let code = "EH00012".replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // strip all non-numeric chars
let num = parseInt(code, 10); // final number 12
```

which should result in what you are looking for `12`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\d/g` and `/\D/g` to replace digit and non-digit portions of string, `while` loop to concatenate `"0"` to portions of string following incrementing number portion if `.length` of both portions of string are less than original string `.length`

```js
let str = "EH00011";

const len = str.length;

function incrementNumberInString(s, l = len) {
  let [chars, nums] = [s.replace(/\d/g, ""), `${+s.replace(/\D/g, "") + 1}`];
  while (chars.length + nums.length < l) { chars += "0" };
  return chars + nums;
};

str = incrementNumberInString(str);

console.log(str);

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  str = incrementNumberInString(str);
  console.log(str);
}
```